# Linear Differential Equation as $t \rightarrow -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, dynamical-systems

Consider the linear diffeq $$\dot{x} = Ax$$

The general solution has the form $$x(t) = c_{1}e^{\lambda_{1}t}v_{1}+c_{2}e^{\lambda_{2}t}v_{2}$$ if $A = V \Lambda V^{-1}$ and so is diagonalizable.

An observation one makes after looking at a few graphs is that the trajectories satisfy the following properties:

Assuming $0>\lambda_{1}>\lambda_{2}$

$x(t)$ becomes parallel to the direction with smallest absolute eigenvalue as $t\rightarrow \infty$,

and $x(t)$ becomes parallel to the direction with largest absolute eigenvalue as $t\rightarrow -\infty$.

More specifically, how do I show the above statement?

Comment: Try to consider equation with both eigenvalues  the same

Comment: When you say $x(t)$ becomes parallel, do you mean the time plot or the phase trajectory?

Comment: @Arastas I mean the trajectory

Comment: Then it is not clear what exactly you mean by "parallel" and "direction". However, loosely saying, you can think that $e^{\lambda_2 t}$ decays way faster and thus the trajectory is similar to $e^{\lambda_1 t}$. Is that what you mean?